# Как сделать уникальную запись в базе данных в промежутке времени?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

имею таблицу `Table_A` где есть 2 столбца с данными `Date`, к примеру `Date_from`, `Date_to` и есть поле какого-то значения `Val`. Так вот я хочу чтобы это поле было уникальным в промежутке времени от `Date_from` до `Date_to`. Как можно это реализовать? Пример: у меня есть запись 1 с временем од `18:00` до `20:00` того же дня, со значением `Val = 1`. Я добавляю новую запись 2, с инным значение `Val = 5`, но в том же промежутке времени, и `СУБД` должна запретить это сделать и выбросить исключение.

Comment: вот триггер и напишите

Comment: Если интервалы не пересекаются, достаточно сделать уникальной комбинацию столбцов Date_from, Date_to

Comment: кроме Date_from, Date_to надо еще Val в уникальный индекс добавить

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov ок, я сделаю 2 стобца уникальными, к примеру от 16:00 до 20:00 и ещё во второй записе од 17:00 до 19:00 и это входит в первый промежуток, но будет добавлено в бд. Пока что среди ответов одна вода, как обычно.

Comment: Вам же написал @SergeyMoiseenko что это будет работать только "если интервалы не пересекающиеся"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если интервалы **не пересекаются**, то можно добавить комплексный уникальный индекс по трем полям Date_from, Date_to, Val.

Если же интервалы **пересекаются**, то это задача не может быть решена на уровне базы данных. Это задача уровня приложения.

Comment: Уникальность по трем столбцам - это неправильно, ибо
18:00, 20:00, 1  и 18:00, 20:00, 5 - уникальны, но нарушают требования задачи. Я писал, что уникальность должна быть по двум столбцам. Но если автор вопроса считает этот ответ лучшим, это его право. :-)